# how to get an extension of any URL's content in the flutter

Tags: flutter

String savename = "VID_${DateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(DateTime.now())}.mp4";
String savePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/$savename";

```
                                    try {
                                      await Dio().download(
                                          "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW4At7ozGFQ&list=RDeW4At7ozGFQ",
                                          savePath,
                                          onReceiveProgress: (received, total) {
                                            if (total != -1) {
                                              print("${(received / total * 100).toStringAsFixed(0)}%");
                                            }
                                          });
                                      print("File is saved to download folder.");
                                    } on DioError catch (e) {
                                      print(e.message);
                                    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what are you asking? Not clear

Answer (score 0):

Cannot download Youtube videos like that. The result will be a html page for that video.

Comment: this should probably be a comment instead of an answer !!!